# cookie getting lost between page navigation

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I have a cookie set like this:

`$_COOKIE['admin'] = 'foo';`

Now the first time, I can see this cookie getting serialized using `var_dump($_COOKIE['admin'])` So, I removed that cookie and just placed this instead.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['admin']){
  echo 'hello admin';
}else{
  echo 'hello visitor';
}
```

Normally this should work for all pages, but it only works once. Meaning, if I browse index page, it works, if I navigate to other page (same website) then comeback to the index page, the cookie gets lost. And there is nothing to destroy/unset any cookie/session in any page.

What could be the problem here

Comment: Can you show some more of your code?

Comment: @qwertynl those are the only codes that are about cookies.

Comment: Have you got this working yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make cookie work in all pages, use like this

```
$value = 'foo';
setcookie('admin', $value, time() + (60 * 60 * 24));
```

Now, a cookie named 'admin' with value 'foo' will be available for 1 day. The path parameter is optional. But if you set it to "/", it will be availabel within entire domain.

Comment: I was going to, but it worked for only few seconds. I am no longer sure what the problem is. I don't think my browser is destroying the cookies.

Comment: if your browser is not destroying the cookies, destroy it like following

    setcookie('admin', '', time() - 3600);

Here, you set cookie named admin to empty ('') and delete the admin cookie by setting it expirations to an hour ago (3600) i.e setting time in the past. This should be in logout page. OR, you can delete cookies manually from browser.

Comment: He cookie is getting destroyed, for a reasons I an not understand. Anyway, I excepted since It's unlikely I will get a right answer soon

Answer (score 4):

I think you're supposed to set cookie values like this:

```
setcookie("name","value", $time, "/");
```

This is covered [here](https://www.php.net/setcookie) in the PHP docs.

Comment: `setcookie(
    "admin",
    "Nov 25",
    time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60)
  );`

Comment: I set the cookie using the above method. Is there anything wrong with it

Comment: You're missing the 4th parameter, the path.

Comment: I guess that is what I don't understand. The path to where exactly? I am working on root folder (`public_html`)

Comment: It is explained in the link I provided, read the 'path' section.

Comment: setcookie("name","value", $time, "/", "www.yoursite.com");

Comment: I think you parameter order was wrong. Which is why I gave up yesterday, but I tried the other answer today. and it worked. thanks anyway. +1

Comment: According to the docs it's correct. Can I ask what you tried and what resolved it?